# How do I remove the default value from a column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

A column in a table has a default value of sysdate and I want to change it so it gets no default value, how do I do this?

Answer (score 57):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable MODIFY YourColumn DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: This is not completely true. You do not remove the default value you set it to `NULL`. The default value cannot be removed, Oracle docs say: "If a column has a default value, then you can use the DEFAULT clause to change the default to NULL, but you cannot remove the default value completely. That is, if a column has ever had a default value assigned to it, then the DATA_DEFAULT column of the USER_TAB_COLUMNS data dictionary view will always display either a default value or NULL."

Comment: @Michael-O Is that functionally equivalent to when there is no `DEFAULT`? (If it is, one has to wonder why they don't just make it consistent and internally give everything a `DEFAULT` of `NULL` by default. As an end user, I shouldn't have to care about internal details like that.)

Comment: @jpmc26, you're right that they are *functionally* equivalent. However, there are cases where [it affects the output of database introspection, as I wrote in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37265135/20789). (This is only one of many stupid corner cases that lead me to conclude that Oracle is an extremely programmer-unfriendly database.)

Comment: @DanLenski - I fully disagree with that conclusion.

Comment: @alexherm, how so? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Oracle is no more unfriendly than any other platform.  There are APIs for just about everything, the environment is quite stable, and support and documentation is halfway decent most of the time.  What platforms do you prefer working with and why?

Answer (score 17):

[Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8481582/20789) is correct in the sense that a column with `DEFAULT NULL` is *functionally* equivalent to having never defined a default value for that column in the first place: if a column has no default value, inserting a new row without specifying a value for that column results in `NULL`.

**However**, Oracle internally represents the two cases distinctly, as can be seen by looking at the [`ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` system view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm#I1020277). (This applies to Oracle 10.x, 11.x, and 12.x, and probably to older versions as well.)

1. The case where a column has been created, or `ALTER`ed, with `DEFAULT NULL`:

   ```
   create table foo (bar varchar2(3) default null);

   select default_length, data_default from all_tab_columns where table_name='FOO';

   => default_length    data_default
      --------------    ------------
      4                 NULL

   select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','FOO') from dual;

   => CREATE TABLE "FOO"
      (    "BAR" VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT NULL
           …
      )
   ```
2. No default ever specified:

   ```
   create table foo (bar varchar2(3));

   select default_length, data_default from all_tab_columns where table_name='FOO';

   => default_length    data_default
      --------------    ------------
      (null)            (null)

   select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','FOO') from dual;

   => CREATE TABLE "FOO"
      (    "BAR" VARCHAR(3)
           …
      )
   ```

As shown above, there is an important case where this otherwise-meaningless distinction makes a difference in Oracle's output: when using [`DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1019414) to extract the table definition.

If you are using `GET_DDL()` to introspect your database, then you will get slightly different DDL output for *functionally-identical* tables.

This is really quite annoying when using `GET_DDL()` for version control and comparison among multiple instances of a database, and there is no way to avoid it, other than to manually modify the output of `GET_DDL()`, or to completely recreate the table with no default value.

Comment: I'd take a look at DROP DEFAULT; I don't know if it's exactly equal to default null but seems more specific.

Comment: As of Oracle 12, it has no `DROP DEFAULT` ☹. This is exactly the problem and the reason why we need to work around it with a `DEFAULT NULL`. (Any references to `DROP DEFAULT` that you find on oracle.com are likely related to MySQL… which is a completely separate database now owned by Oracle.)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do what you want is to recreate the table.

It is pretty easy to do in Toad, just right click on the table and select "Rebuild Table".  Toad will create script which will rename the table and recreate a new table. The script will recreate indexes, constraints, foreign keys, comments, etc... and populate the table with data.

Just modify the script to remove "default null" after the column in question.

Comment: One can drop the column and then add it again.
`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN mycolumn;
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD mycolumn DATE;`

Comment: This does work, the only issue is that it will move the column to the bottom of the col list.  If you want to preserve the column order, drop and recreate the table.